# How to fix 'Argument data to tableXXX is required' in django-tables2?

Tags: django, django-haystack, django-tables2

I'm setting up a webstore manager and I'm relying on django-tables2 package to show a list of products using the SimpleTableMixin. I want to add the filter/search capability to the view. As recommended by the django-tables2 package one can rely on django-filter package to provide filtering. However, it the case of a model with many fields it becomes almost impossible to query and develop forms for those efficiently. My goal is to use django-haystack to have a single input search form as a mean to query the model instances which should be displayed in a similar table/form.

I've tried to add the SimpleTableMixin to the django-haystack package generic SearchView. However I keep on getting the following error:

```
TypeError at /manager/front/products/
Argument data to ProductTable is required
```

So far my implementation goes as follow:

view:

```
# ############## Products ############## (previous implementation with django-filter)
# @method_decorator(staff_member_required, name='dispatch')
# class ProductList(SingleTableMixin, FilterView):
#     model = Product
#     table_class = tables.ProductTable
#     filterset_class = filters.ProductFilter
#     template_name = 'manager/front/products/product_list.html'

############## Products ##############
@method_decorator(staff_member_required, name='dispatch')
class ProductList(SingleTableMixin, SearchView):
    model = Product
    table_class = tables.ProductTable
    template_name = 'manager/front/products/product_list.html'
```

tables:

```
import django_tables2 as tables
from front.models import Product

class ProductTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        template_name = 'django_tables2/bootstrap.html'
```

search_indexes.py:

```
from haystack import indexes
from front.models import Product

class ProductIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)

    def get_model(self):
        return Product
```

urls:

```
path('front/products',views.ProductList.as_view(),name="manage_products"),
```

template:

```
{% extends 'base_site.html' %}
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
{% block content_title %}Manage Products{% endblock%}
{% block content %}
<form action="" method="get" class="form form-inline">
    {{ form }}
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
{% render_table table %}
{% endblock %}
```

How can I remove that error and provide efficient search abilities to my list views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you are using `haystack.generic_views.SearchView` and *not* `haystack.views.SearchView`? Please notice that on https://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/latest/views_and_forms.html it says:

> As of version 2.4 the views in haystack.views.SearchView are deprecated in favor of the new generic views in haystack.generic_views.SearchView which use the standard Django class-based views which are available in every version of Django which is supported by Haystack.

Thus if you're using `haystack.views.SearchView` then the `get_context_data` of `SingleTableMixin` will never be called thus no `table` will be put in your context (i.e `table` will be empty). Actually because I dislike the behavior of `{% render_table %}` when its parameter is empty (it behaves different than the other Django tags/filters i.e it throws an exception while the django ones silently ignore that) I usually put it inside some `{% if table %}` checks.

*UPDATE*

It seems that for whatever reason the data is not passed to the table. I am not sure why, I can't test it right now but from a quick look at the source code your implementation *should have been working* (considering that SearchView has a `get_queryset` and `TableMixin` uses the `get_queryset` to retrieve its data). In any case you try overriding some methods of `TableMixin` to make sure that the table is properly returned (take a look at TableMixin here: https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/django_tables2/views.html).

I think the most definite solution would be to just bite the bullet and override `get_table` yourself. So, try adding something like this to your class:

```
def get_table(self, **kwargs):
    table_class = self.get_table_class()
    # I only change this line from the original to make sure that the self.get_queryset() is called to return the data
    table = table_class(data=self.get_queryset(), **kwargs)
    return RequestConfig(self.request, paginate=self.get_table_pagination(table)).configure(
        table
    )
```

One idea that just popped in my mind. Is there a possibility that the `get_queryset()` method of `SearchView` returns `None` due to bad configuration or whatever?

Comment: I'm using haystack.generic_views.SearchView. Could you provide an implementation example? I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Actually, your solution based on the override of  the get_table method is working since the table is only filled with the indexed data, not the complete model object instance data. Does one must indexed all model fields manually? Regards.

Comment: Great I'm glad it worked. Unfortunately I'm not very familiar with django-haystack so I can't answer the question. Maybe ask in the project's GitHub? Best regards!